# Importing xml files into java class. Is it possible in that way?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I am wondering if it is possible to import xml file in that way:

```
import org.hibernate.*;
import org.hibernate.cfg.*;
```

I have hibernate.cfg.xml in src folder (the same with .java files), but still Netbeans can't find it when I want to import it in the way as I mentioned above.

How should I resolve this problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You only import java classes.  *xml could be considered as resources. There are APIs to help : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String) or http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to import xml in that way. You should use something like this:

```
ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream("hibernate.cfg.xml");
```